# C# client consuming java-websphere SOAP service

Tags: c#, java, soap, websphere

I am trying to consume a java-based service from .Net 4.0. (C# Console/Windows Service)
I have added the service reference using VS's  `Add Service Reference` Dialog.

The service is hosted on WebSphere 8 and WSDL definition is generated using cxf.
Client app is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. But I don't think any windows update is applied after SP1.

Problem is *from time to time* All the calls to service methods return an exception. The error is as follows:

```
The content type text/xml;charset=UTF8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).  
If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.  
The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions name="MyServiceImplService" targetNamespace="http://impl.webService.myService.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://webService.myService.com/" xmlns:ns2="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://impl.webService.myService.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
<wsdl:import location="http://10.1.1.1/myService/webService/myService?wsdl=myService.wsdl" namespace="http://webService.myService.com/"></wsdl:import>  
<wsdl:binding name="MyServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:myService">
<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"></soap12:binding>
<wsdl:operation name="disableCard">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="" style="documen'..
```

Here's my client app's WCF config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <customBinding>
         <binding name="MyServiceImplServiceSoapBinding">
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
            <httpTransport />
         </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
       <endpoint address="http://10.1.1.1/myService/webService/myService?wsdl"
           binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceImplServiceSoapBinding"
           contract="MyServiceReference.myService" name="MyServiceImplPort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

- I don't think this has anything to do with WCF configuration since all the methods work fine and all of a sudden, All of them return this exception.
- The error seems to show up randomly with no apparent reason. Sometimes after 2 days and ~1,000,000 requests and sometimes after half an hour. But when this exception shows up, every call to the service returns this exception.
- On the service side, there's no log that the call even reaches the java application. Seems like WebSphere sends the wsdl definition instead of passing my call to service.
- Closing and relaunching the client app does not make the error go away. Only a complete system restart makes the error to disappear. (**Update:** it seems like removing ?wsdl from the endpoint address, removed the need to restart the system and restarting the client app is enough to make it work again.)
- When facing the error, I have called the service methods with Soap UI and got the results with no exception. So there's probably nothing wrong on the service side.

My only guess is that this is a bug in .Net Framework 4.0.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was going to ask about testing with another client, so your soapUI test confirms that it's not the service getting in a bad state. Can you see at the HTTP server log, or even a lower-level network monitor, whether the request does reach the server at all, and if what it looks like?

Comment: @dbreaux I'm trying to do that. Still not possible. however, it seems like removing `?wsdl` from the  endpoint address, removed the need to restart the system and restarting the client app is enough to make it work again.

Comment: Oh, yeah. ?wsdl shouldn't be in the endpoint address. I didn't notice that.